# Constructing a random array of given size from all elements of another array, with the condition of upper and lower bounds for their occurance

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have defined an array called `box` as follows:

```
var box = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j];
```

I am generating random number between 0 to the length of the array. In this case the length of the array is 10:

```
var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * box.length);
```

I retrieve values from the `box` array by passing the random number as an array index:

```
var random_element = box[random_number];
```

I need to create a new array called `room` using the elements from `box`, so that:

1. the size of `room` is 40,
2. every element from `box` is present in `room`,
3. each element from `box` must occur in 'room` at least 3 times,
4. each element from `box` must occur in 'room` at most 5 times.

Comment: what does this question have to do with each programming language mentioned in the question tags?

Comment: this array_count_values will work for you.  $a=array("A","Cat","Dog","A","Dog");
print_r(array_count_values($a));
?>

Comment: result will be Array ( [A] => 2 [Cat] => 1 [Dog] => 2 )

Comment: @kirangadhvi Thank you . please see my condition for creating  new array .

Comment: Are the elements in `box` unique, or might `a` be equal to `b` for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Idea

The possible approach is to fill array first by the minimum amount of each element, then randomly add elements until the array is filled up. Of course we should take care about maximum bound too.

### Code

```
MINIMUM_AMOUNT = 3
MAXIMUM_AMOUNT = 5
// We also need to track how much of each element we have
// Fill minimum amount of each element
for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < MINIMUM_AMOUNT; j++) {
        room.push(box[i])
    }
    // At first the are only 3 elements
    count[i] = MINIMUM_AMOUNT
}
// Fill the rest of the array
while (room.length != 40) {
    random_index = Math.trunc(10 * Math.random())
    random_elem = box[random_index]
    // If this element did not yet reach its limit
    if (count[random_index] < MAXIMUM_AMOUNT) {
        room.push(random_elem)
        count[random_index]++
    }
}
```

### Shuffling

For now your array will look like `[a, a, a, b, b, b, ..., j, j, j, a, e, b, ...]`. If you need items to be more *randomly* placed, consider using a [shuffling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score 0):

I think @Destiners idea is perfect for this job. I just would like to share my implementation of that idea. I use the `room` array both to hold the characters and also for the lookup table. So for instance `room.a` will give the count of "a" characters in the `room` array. Then applied a generic proper shuffling.

```js
Array.prototype.shuffle = function(){
  var i = this.length,
      j;
  while (i > 1) {
    j = ~~(Math.random()*i--);
    [this[i],this[j]] = [this[j],this[i]];
  }
return this;
};

var box = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"];
   room = box.reduce((p,c) => (p[c] = 3, p.push(...c.repeat(3).split("")),p),[]);
  while (room.length < 40) {
    var c = box[~~(Math.random()*box.length)];
    room[c] < 5 && (room.push(c), room[c]++);
  }
  room.shuffle();
console.log(room);
console.log(room.a);
```